# Вычесть две даты и получить время Carbon

Tags: laravel, carbon

как получить время - минуты и секунды из разницы между датами?

сделал так, но в секундах 4 цифры - 1234

```
$current = Carbon::now();
$date = Carbon::parse($numbers['date_send']);
$time .= $date->diffInMinutes($current);
$time .= ':'.$date->diffInSeconds($current,'absolute');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы получаете разницу в секундах и в минутах. Это некорректно. Так как если разница будет 2 минуты, в результате у вас получится:

```
2 минуты, 120 секунд.
```

Задачу можно решить так:

```
Carbon::parse('2020-06-09 08:20:00')->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%i minutes, %s seconds')
```

Реузльтат:

```
18 minutes, 41 seconds
```

При этом, надо учитывать, что если разница более 1 дня, то это не будет учтено. То есть более 24 часов в результате не получится. Но можно вывести и дни и месяцы и годы.